# Scraping from Json using beautifulsoup and urllib

Tags: python, urllib, scrape

I'm learning some scraping on a sample website that uses json. For instance, take the following sample website: http://www.charitystars.com/product/juve-chelsea-3-0-champions-league-jersey-autographed-by-giorgio-chiellini. The source code is here `view-source:https://www.charitystars.com/product/juve-chelsea-3-0-champions-league-jersey-autographed-by-giorgio-chiellini`. I would like to get the information at lines 388-396:

```
<script>
    var js_data = {"first_time_bid":true,"yourbid":0,"product":{"id":55,"item_number":"P55","type":"PRODUCT","fixed":0,"price":1000,"tot_price":1000,"min_bid_value":1010,"currency":"EUR","raise_bid":10,"stamp_end":"2013-06-14 12:00:00","bids_number":12,"estimated_value":200,"extended_time":0,"url":"https:\/\/www.charitystars.com\/product\/juve-chelsea-3-0-champions-league-jersey-autographed-by-giorgio-chiellini","conversion_value":1,"eid":0,"user_has_bidded":false},"bid":{"id":323,"uid":126,"first_name":"Fabio","last_name":"Gastaldi","company_name":"","is_company":0,"title":"fab1","nationality":"IT","amount":1000,"max_amount":0,"table":"","stamp":1371166006,"real_stamp":"2013-06-14 01:26:46"}};
    var p_currency = '€';
    var conversion_value = '1';
    var merch_items = [];
    var gallery_items = [];

    var inside_gala = false;
</script>
```

and save each variable in quotes (i.e., "id", "item_number", "type", ...) in a variable with the same name.

So far I managed to run the following

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
import re
import json
import time
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from pandas import DataFrame

import urllib2
hdr = {"User-Agent": "My Agent"}

req = urllib2.Request(http://www.charitystars.com/product/juve-chelsea-3-0-champions-league-jersey-autographed-by-giorgio-chiellini)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

htmlSource = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource)

title = soup.find_all("span", {"itemprop": "name"}) # get the title

script_soup = soup.find_all("script")
```

For some reason, script_soup has a lot of information that I don't need. I believe that the part that I need is in `script_soup[9]`, but I don't know how to access it (in an efficient way). I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is indeed in `script_soup[9]`. The issue is that this is a `json` string hardcoded in a script tag. You can get the string in plaintext with `script_soup[9].string` and then extract the `json` string with `split()` (as in my example) or with `regex`. Then load the string as a python dictionary with `json.loads()`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame
import json

hdr = {"User-Agent": "My Agent"}
response = requests.get("http://www.charitystars.com/product/juve-chelsea-3-0-champions-league-jersey-autographed-by-giorgio-chiellini", headers=hdr)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
script_soup = soup.find_all("script")
data = json.loads(script_soup[9].string.split('= ')[1].split(';')[0])
```

The data is now stored in the variable `data`. You can parse it as you like or load it in `pandas` with `pd.DataFrame(data)`.

Comment: Thank you! I would really like to save the variables "amount", "bids_number", "conversion_value", "currency", "estimated_value", "extended_time", "first_name", "id", "last_name", "max_amount", "min_bid_value", "nationality",  "price", "raise_bid", "real_stamp", "stamp_end", "uid" in different vectors.  When I create the dataframe`dat = pd.DataFrame(data)` it gives me a matrix with 4 columns, which I don't know how to use. Can I simply create each variable as in `item_number = data.find_all("'item_number'")` (or similar) and then put it in a vector?

Comment: I tried the following without success:
`import re
regex = []
regex = re.compile('"raise_bid":([0-9]*)')
raise_bid = regex.findall(data.encode('ascii','ignore').replace("'",""))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'`
I was hoping to create a variable called `raise_bid`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with vector. Do you mean variable? You can do so: `amount = data['bid']['amount']`, `bids_number = data['product']['bids_number']` etc. `data` is a dictionary, not a string - so don't use regex. You can access the items by key, plenty of info on the [internet](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) on how dictionaries work.

Answer (score 1):

if u can use `requests` and `lxml` modules u can use this

## updated as per OP

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import json

header = {
    'User-Agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                   ' Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36 Edg/85.0.564.51'),
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}


url='http://www.charitystars.com/product/juve-chelsea-3-0-champions-league-jersey-autographed-by-giorgio-chiellini'
a = requests.get(url,headers=header)

a = html.fromstring(a.text).xpath('//*[@class="page-content"]/script/text()')[0]
a = a.replace('\n','').replace(' ','')
b = a.split(';')
b = [i.split('=') for i in b]
c = json.loads(b[0][1])
c['product']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! My question then is how to access the variables inside b[0][1]? I would like to create a variable for each variable inside `"product":{ ... }` so to store them in a vector when I scrape some more listings.

Comment: `c = b[0][1].replace('"product":{','').split(',')` & `c = [i.split(':') for i in c]`

Comment: Wow! this is perfect! The only problem I have is that for `c[11]`, it gives `[u'"stamp_end"', u'"2013-06-1412', u'00', u'00"']`, which is the wrong date because `c[11][1]` returns `u'"2013-06-1412'`, while it should only be `2013-06-14`, so that I can save `12` as a `hour` variable.